# GL Func Subtract Cocos2d

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, mask, blending, glblendfunc

Does anyone know how to change the blending mode for a specific sprite in Cocos2d 2.x to GL_FUNC_SUBTRACT?

Ive tried a few things, but basically I'm trying to create a layer mask using a white (or black) circle and hiding the alpha.

Answer (score 2):

You could try implementing your wrapper Sprite for that purpose. That class (let's say SubSprite) should inherit the CCNode class and have a single member, a regular CCSprite that you want to draw with GL_FUNC_SUBTRACT.

Override the draw method with something like this:

```
-(void) draw{
  int oldEquation;
  glGetIntegerv( GL_BLEND_EQUATION_ALPHA, &oldEquation);
  glBlendEquation( GL_FUNC_SUBTRACT );
  [targetSprite draw];
  glBlendEquation( oldEquation );
}
```

I have not tried it out, but it should work and you do not have to rewrite the whole sprite drawing function.